# Problema no sublime para rodar código em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text, sublime-text-2, sublimerepl

Ao dar <kbd>**CRTL+B**</kbd>  no sublime 2, para rodar meu código em python, aparece essa mensagem de erro, alguém sabe o que é?

```
Decode error - output not utf-8]
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Rosangela\\Desktop\\Leo\\Estudo\\Exercicios_Python\\teste14.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Rosangela\Desktop\Leo\Estudo\Exercicios_Python]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Delphi7SE\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Delphi7SE\Projects\BPL]
[Finished]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O caminho do Python não está no seu PATH (variáveis de ambiente).

Veja a tela abaixo para configurar:

[image: Variáveis de Ambiente]

Comment: Olá, obrigado funcionou, porem quando fui executar meu codigo deu o seguinte erro.


Insira o valor do peso(KG): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rosangela\Desktop\Leo\Estudo\Exercicios_Python\exercicio2_questao03.py", line 1, in <module>
    peso = float(input('Insira o valor do peso(KG): '))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: @LeonardoVillela Isto é escopo de outra pergunta. Se quiser perguntar, fique à vontade.