# Rodar arquivo python(pelo terminal) pelo Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Atualmente uso o Atom para escrever meus programas em Python. Porém, quero migrar para o sublime text por questões de comodidade e por ser um programa mais leve. Uso um plugin no Atom chamado: [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run). Ele me permite que quando aperte `F5` ele rode o arquivo `.py` em um terminal externo. Gostaria de fazer o mesmo com o Sublime Text, já tentei plugins nele como: Terminal(So abre o terminal na pasta do arquivo), Terminality(nada funcionou), SublimeREPL(Esse funciona, mas, n abre em um terminal a parte). Como poderia resolver? ajustando as configurações do plugin Terminal(Eu tentei editar, mas não resultou no que queria)?

Arquivo: Terminal.sublime-settings

```
{
//The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
// See https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#examples for examples
"terminal": "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",

// A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
// overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
// dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
// commands
"parameters": ["python","-u" ,"$file"],

// An environment variables changeset. Default environment variables used for the
// terminal are inherited from sublime. Use this mapping to overwrite/unset. Use
// null value to indicate that the environment variable should be unset.
"env": {}
}
```

Arquivo: Default(Windows).sublime-keymap

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "open_terminal",},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+t"], "command": "open_terminal_project_folder" }
]
```

Comment: De curiosidade, você tentou simplesmente dar um Control + B? Eu acho que até tem pronto perfil pra .py no Sublime, nem precisa fazer nada. Confira se já tem no menu: **Tools -> Build System -> Python** - e depois Control B - Não se esqueça de verificar se o python.exe (ou equivalente, dependendo do OS) está no seu path

Comment: Creio que o que você quer está colateralmente resolvido aqui: [Problema no sublime para rodar código em python](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21118/problema-no-sublime-para-rodar-c%c3%b3digo-em-python)

Comment: Ou aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175788/70

Comment: o segundo link funcionou! Muito Obrigado!!